# Jetty auto restart with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

**Problem:**
I can't figure why jetty is not automatically restart on code changes on IntelliJ, even if configured on pom.

**Description:**
I'm starting using IntelliJ , and I've loaded an existing project from my repository.
This project is build on Maven, and I have a pom which specify to autoreload every 2 seconds on changes.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.9.v20160517</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I was on Eclipse, this scan was triggered when i saved a file and was working without problem: since intelliJ doesn't have a save since saves automatically, I can't figure out how to trigger the auto-restart into jetty. Atm nothing happens when I edit my code, and restart never triggers.

What I'm doing wrong, or what is missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed by upgrading the plugin version to *9.4.11.v20180605*:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
        <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```